# PySimpleGUI generates error message when started from command line

Tags: python, macos, pysimplegui

When starting a simple PySimpleGUI app from command line, the following error message is sent to stderr:

> Mac OS Version is 13.1 and patch enabled so applying the patch
>
> Applyting Mac OS 12.3+ Alpha Channel fix.  Your default Alpha Channel is now 0.99

Here is the simple code that exhibits the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.Window(title="Hello World", layout=[[]], margins=(100, 50)).read()
```

I have run the following after installing Mac OS 13.1:

```
brew upgrade
brew reinstall python
brew reinstall python-tk
pip install pysimplegui
```

None of these actions had any effect.

I've run searches for the error message in quotes, and there are no hits.

I assumed that the error above was caused by something being out of date.  However the error doesn't indicate what generated it, so I am chasing a ghost right now.

Comment: Why are you interpreting that as an error message?  It seems to be the exact opposite of an error message - a problem has been *prevented*, rather than occurred.

Comment: Two things: 1) this behavior never happened before and I've found no documentation regarding why it's happening; and, 2) the misspelling of "Applying" as "Applyting" makes me wonder if my system has been hacked.

Comment: Seems to be a workaround: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5471#issuecomment-1362606150

Comment: Search for `Applyting` in here, you will find it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/master/PySimpleGUI.py

Comment: Release notes https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#4602-pysimplegui-26-jul-2022.  Maybe searching the PySimpleGUI docs for 0.99 would have been helpful.  Feel free to open an issue on the project's github suggesting an improvement to the error message display.